# OSX Yosemite update breaks pow.cx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, osx-yosemite, pow.cx

After upgrading to OSX Yosemite my existing pow.cx install does not work. Upgrading to the latest pow.cx did not work. Also restarting it via the Activity Monitor did not do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with pow.cx on my two macbooks after upgrading OSX to Yosemite.

---

**First,** One of the two Macs is fixed by updating pow

```
curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
curl get.pow.cx | sh
```

It fixed one of the two computers.

---

**Then**, for the second mac, pow is fixed by removing network configuration & preference file. Manually trashing the network plist files should be your first line of trouble shooting. This is one of those tricks that consistently resolves even the most stubborn wireless problems on Macs. Updating to Yosemite might have a corrupt preference file. Follow steps below:

1. Turn off Wi-Fi from Wireless menu item
2. Go to finder `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
3. Within this folder locate and select files:
   com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
   com.apple.network.identification.plist
   com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist 
   NetworkInterfaces.plist 
   preferences.plist
4. Move all of these files into a folder on your Desktop called ‘wifi backups’ or something similar – we’re backing these up just in case you break something but if you regularly backup your Mac you can just delete the files instead since you could restore from Time Machine if need be
5. Reboot the Mac. This forces OS X to recreate all network configuration files.
6. Turn ON WI-Fi from the wireless network menu again.

For more detailed steps, please see [Fix Wi-Fi Problems in OS X Yosemite](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/)

This issue costed me 4 hours.

Answer (score 11):

Uninstalling (!) and reinstalling fixed the issue.

```
curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
curl get.pow.cx | sh
```

Comment: You likely also have to do this anytime you reboot : `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf; sudo pfctl -e`

Comment: @joost: You asked and answered your own question within the same minute. You accepted your own answer to make sure your own answer goes to the top. However the answer below by Likun Hu (a relatively in-experienced user) has additional information which is helpful for cases where your answer doesn't work. Would you consider accepting her answer instead? You will earn +2 reputation for it, and you will no lose any, but it seems like the right thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

For me this was due to the new DNS resolver. Specifically it wouldn't work when wifi was turned off or OSX believed it was offline.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/

If you only have the problem when offline, you can use powder to add your pow domains to /etc/hosts:

```
gem install powder
powder host
```

It might not work with subdomains however